# To Prove using the Integral Mean Value Theorem

Tags: integration, proof-verification, definite-integrals

Hi Guys I am attempting the following question its a proof and i am hoping you all can guide me accordingly

$$let f,g \in C[a,b], h \in R[a,b]$$
$$h(x) \geq m, m > 0, \forall x \in [a,b]$$

Use the Integral Mean value Theorem to prove that if

$$\int^b_af(x)h(x)dx = \int^b_ag(x)h(x)dx$$

The there exists a c $ \in$ [a,b] such that f(c) = g(c)

My attempt at this proof shown below:-

$$\int^b_ah(x) dx > 0$$

$$\int^b_af(x)h(x)dx > 0$$

$$f \in C [a,b]$$

since i do not know what f(x) is i decide to pull out the $f(x)$ as f(x is defined on [a,b] i assume this to be some value)

$$f(x)\int^b_ah(x)dx > 0$$

$$\int^b_ah(x)dx = area, under, the, graph$$

$$f(c) = \frac{\int^b_ah(x)dx}{b-a}$$

Therefore based on finding the average integral related to the question

$$f(c) = f(x)\frac{\int^b_ah(x)dx}{f(x)(b-a)} > 0$$

and similarly

$$g(c) = g(x)\frac{\int^b_ah(x)dx}{g(x)(b-a)}> 0$$

I am not sure if i am going about this the right way and was hoping for some help in trying to figure out this proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since
$$\int_a^b f(x) h(x)\,dx=\int_a^b g(x)h(x)\,dx.$$
We know that
$$\int_a^b\left(f(x)-g(x)\right)h(x)\,dx=0.$$
And we get that there is a $c\in[a,b]$ such that
$$0= \int_a^b\left(f(x)-g(x)\right)h(x)\,dx =(f(c)-g(c))\int_a^b h(x)\,dx.$$

Since $h(x)\geq m>0$, we have $\int_a^b h(x)\,dx>0$, which means 
$$f(c)-g(c)=0.$$
That's what we like.

Comment: thanks @ling for the help and the notation i appreciate it